How can I initiate a new URL request using an already loaded WKWebView?
I have opened a WKWebView with "https://www.google.com", for example. After that, I put my app in the background. When I try to open a new URL request in the same web view with a new link, like "https://www.youtube.com", by redirecting the app, it doesn't work. I've put a listener function to detect the new URL and called "webView.load(newURLRequest)". However, the web view never loads the new URL request.
I have tried to solve this issue by adding a delay through DispatchQueue. Adding a delay sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I also tried using NavigationDelegate, but it still didn't help. Below is my code:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshData), name: NSNotification.Name("refreshweb"), object: nil)
}

@objc func refreshData() {
    let url = URL (string: "https://www.youtube.com")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webview.load(requestObj)
}


You mean you are trying to open a new URL while your app is in the background?

Yes. Basically, I am trying to scan a QR code with the camera and load the URL obtained from the scan in an app that is running in the background. However, I am unable to load the new URL.
